# While loop in assembly with increment only prints once, can't figure out why(nasm)

Tags: assembly, while-loop, counter, nasm

I've tried all sorts of <, <= to commands for the exit but it will only print the message once. Trying to get it to print on each iteration. I've got a ton of tabs open and have tried a lot, but can't figure this one out.

```
    mov rax,0
    mov rbx,6
WhileLoop: 
    Cmp rax,rbx         ;loop termination condition (rax<6)
    jge WhileDone       ;if !<6, exit while loop
    mov rdi, message2   ;print message
    mov al, 0           ;print message
    call printf         ;print message
    inc rax             ;rax=rax+1
    jmp WhileLoop       ;next iteration 
WhileDone:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the procedure "printf" is modifying `rax` or `rbx`. So, let's preserve them before "printf", and restore them after "printf" :

```
    mov rax,0
    mov rbx,6
WhileLoop: 
    Cmp rax,rbx         ;loop termination condition (rax<6)
    jge WhileDone       ;if !<6, exit while loop
    PUSH RAX
    PUSH RBX
    mov rdi, message2   ;print message
    mov al, 0           ;print message
    call printf         ;print message
    POP  RBX
    POP  RAX
    inc rax             ;rax=rax+1
    jmp WhileLoop       ;next iteration 
WhileDone:
```

Comment: That was it! I don't know that I'd have ever figured that out.

Comment: Also note that `al` is of course the least significant byte of `rax` so you yourself already destroy `rax`. As to how to figure it out: 1) read the ABI documentation that tells you about register conventions and 2) use a debugger. PS: `rbx` is preserved by `printf`, but you also must preserve it for your caller.

Comment: I deleted rbx=6 and changed rax to rbx. took out all of the pop/push commands and it worked! That's why it wasn't preserving it (the al).

Comment: It's not just "possible", it's expected.  `RAX` is used for the return code for functions.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, it was possible that "printf" was created by user3866044, so, it was better to post a "safe" solution.